# A expressão Linq não pode ser traduzida ERRO

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou tentado fazer a seguinte consulta SQL com o Linq:

Essa é a estrutura do banco de dados:

| Pessoas | type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| Name | string |
| Age | int |
| Sons | int |

| Pets | type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| Name | string |
| Adopted | bool |
| PersonId | int (foreign key) |

Essa é a cosnulta crua que eu faço no SSMS

```
SELECT a.Id, count(b.Id) as pets, a.Name 
FROM Pessoas AS a
LEFT JOIN Pets AS b
ON a.Id = b.PersonId
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Name
```

Essa é a versão com o Linq que eu fiz no visual studio:

```
var result = from p in _context.People
                         join pet in _context.Pets
                         on p.Id equals pet.Person.Id
                         group p by p.Id into wp
                         from subperson in wp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                         select new Person { Name = subperson.Name, PetsId = subperson.Pets.Count()};
```

E esse é o erro:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Person>()
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Pet>(), 
        outerKeySelector: p => p.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: pet => pet.Person.Id, 
        resultSelector: (p, pet) => new { 
            p = p, 
            pet = pet
         })
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.p.Id, 
        elementSelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.p)
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: wp => wp
            .AsQueryable()
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        resultSelector: (wp, subperson) => new Person{ 
            Name = subperson.Name, 
            PetsId = subperson.Pets
                .AsQueryable()
                .Count() 
        }
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? (Sou iniciante)

Comment: Qual é banco de dados???